# vuejs how to check if key/ID exist in the array

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of `roles` which lists all the roles available. Each user is assigned to 1 or more roles, named `user_roles`.

I am listing all the `roles` as checkboxes, by default marked as unchecked. 
When I select a user, I want to be able to check if the role ID in the list matches an ID from my `user_roles` array.

In php/html I can achieve this by using

```
<?=in_array($user_roles, $role->id) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
```

How can I achieve the same thing in vuejs?

I'm trying the same idea using the below example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="role[]" :value="role.id" :id="'role' + role.id" :checked="in_array(user_roles, role.id)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array's `indexOf` method:

```html
:checked="user_roles.indexOf(role.id) >= 0"
```